Tanstack router not redirecting for authenticated routes
I am using tanstack router and am having issues with my protected routes. As per the documentation I am nesting all my protected routes inside a /_auth folder
This is my /_auth/route.tsx file
export const Route = createFileRoute('/_auth')({
    beforeLoad: ({ context, location }) => {
        console.log(context)

        if (!context.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            throw redirect({
                to: '/login',
                search: {
                    redirect: location.href,
                },
            })
        }
    },
    component: AuthLayout,
})

I can clearly see my authentication context in both the console log and the tanstack router devtools. The isAuthenticated variable is false - the URL itself changes to /login however my _auth/index.tsx component is rendered.
I am using version 1.31.1
Anybody else facing this similar issue?

Dont know why this was downvoted - same issue here https://github.com/TanStack/router/issues/1528

I noticed two things. The "route.tsx" convention isn't documented anymore. I had your problem but my routes.tsx was named index.tsx. I changed it to routes.tsx and it works! ... and I'm confused.
